# Copying a 16 bit integer to a two byte array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, endianness

I am wondering why when I copy a 16 bit number to a two byte array, it results in only copying to the first index of the array.
My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>



using namespace std;


int main(){
    uint16_t my_num = 1; // This should be 0000 0000 0000 0001, right?
    unsigned char my_arr[2]; // This should hold 16 bits, right?

    memcpy(my_arr, &my_num, sizeof(my_num)); // This should make my_arr = {00000000, 00000001}, right?

        printf("%x ", my_arr[0]);
        printf("%x ", my_arr[1]);
        cout << endl;
        // "1 0" is printed out


        return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your machine appears to be little-endian. Consecutive bytes are stored in "reverse" order -- first `0x01`, then `0x00`.

Comment: Looks like endianness got in your way, since you may have gotten `00000001 000000000`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because of [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your platform. The bytes of multi-byte `uint16_t` are stored in the address space lowest-byte-first. You can see what's going on by trying the same program with a number that is larger than 256:

```
uint16_t my_num = 0xABCD;
```

The result will have `0xCD` in the first byte and `0xAB` in the second byte.

You can force a specific endianness by using functions from [`hton`/`ntoh` family](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htons).

Comment: Thanks. This expains it well. Is there a way of doing a "memcpy" that does  not depend on endianness?

Comment: @user98651 `memcpy` does not depend on endianness, it's what is stored in `my_num` that's "reversed" by hardware. You can put it in network order by calling `my_num = htons(my_num);` before `memcpy`, assuming that you have `<arpa/inet.h>`.

Comment: The htons method is what I was looking for. Thanks